# Android-can not edit my xml file in the eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I have not had similar question before since I have used eclipse as the IDE for several years already.

When I import the Android project, I am able to edit the src file where java files located. However, i am unable to edit any file with xml extension.(AndroidManifest.xml and all files in layout folder with xml extension).

I can edit it by using other editors, such as vim.

I dont know why this happened here.

Eclipse: INDIGO

Eclipse SDK: 3.7.2

Please let me know if you have any idea on how to configure it.

Thank you so much.

Regards

Comment: Is ADT plugin isntalled?

Comment: are files' permission correct, are they writable?

Comment: right click the xml file choose open with-->Android Layout Editor

Comment: yes, it has been installed. Everything is right, such as DDMS and so on. except can not edit the xml file in the android project. weired.

Comment: Files are all writable since i can use VIM to edit them and save then run.

Comment: Hi KMI, i dont have Android Layout Editor. I have Android common xml Editor. is this why? can you tell me how to install it?

Comment: then how you edit the layout for New android project ?

Comment: can able to open the xml file in eclipse ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11221/discussion-between-kmi-and-user1336041)

Comment: anyone? this really confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I finally give up to find out why it doesnt work on my eclipse.
However, I then turn to download the other version eclipse and it works perfectly!
So I would assume that might be a compatibility between Android and Eclipse I guess.

here is the version I tried:

Doesnt work: ADT:18

```
         Eclipse: Indigo
         Eclipse SDK
         Version: 3.7.2
         Build id: M20120208-0800
```

Does work  : ADT:18

```
         Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
         Version: Indigo Service Release 2
         Build id: 20120216-1857
```

So if any of you face the same issue, i would suggest you to save your time and download

the latest Eclipse instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in ADT.
Which ADT version you are using ?

Your eclipse must be getting crashed whenever you try to open .xml file,is it?

Comment: The ADT version i am using now is 18.0. However, my eclipse did not get crashed whenI open .xml file. It just opened but I cant not edit it anyway.

Comment: Do you know how to fix it? Downgrade the ADT version?